# How to have if condition for css class?

Tags: css, angular

When editing my component, the column grids also are changed.

Currently, I have this for my **edit-component.html**

```
      <div class="col-6" *ngIf="!edit">
        Column1
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-2" *ngIf="edit">
        Column1
      </div>
      <div class="col-6" *ngIf="!edit">
        Column2
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-2" *ngIf="edit">
        Column2
      </div>
```

And I have this for **edit-component.ts**

```
    edit: boolean = false;
```

This method works and the css is changing when editting or readonly. But is there other way that I can have if condition for *col-12 col-md-5* and *col-6*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) directive.

```
<div [ngClass]="{'col-6': !edit, 'col-sm-2 col-md-4 col-12': edit}">
    Column1
</div>
```

Comment: The only adjustment I'd suggest, is to extract that out to a getter, so that you can take advantage of re-use.  Having that defined on every column element will be a mess.

Comment: Fair point about re-use, however I wouldn't use a getter here because they're executed whenever angular runs change detection. Since this def would make the template harder to read, I'd actually consider extracting this into a pipe. Which also makes it more testable.

Comment: ngClass directive is the way. I just edited how it looks but it works when using ngClass like [ngClass]="edit ? 'col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-2' : 'col-6'"

Comment: @newProgrammer005 that works, just because it works with simple strings.  But the more powerful way of using ngClass involves creating an object like this, so that you can dynamically apply n number of classes based on different conditions.  This illustrates that capability more.  You may also consider the approach I suggested below, which allows for better re-use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Using the NgClass directive, you can apply classes dynamically based on conditions in your typescript class.

For example:
Typescript:

```
get columnClassDef() {
  return {
    'col-6': !this.edit,
    'col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-2': this.edit,
  };
}
```

Html:

```
<div [ngClass]="columnClassDef">
  Column1
</div>
<div [ngClass]="columnClassDef">
  Column2
</div>
```

NgClass will apply the key of the object as a css class on the element, if the value evaluates to true.  It doesn't add the class if the value evaluates to false.

Comment: This definitely makes the template more readable, but `getColumnClassDef` will be re-executed with every change detection cycle.

Comment: @spots It would if it was inline in the template, though, too, wouldn't it?  I think a pure pipe is the only way around that.

Comment: TBH, I'm not sure. The `edit` variable is the only thing that needs to be evaluated, so I guess technically yes there's work being done. In this example however a new object is created every time. It's unlikely to create a problem in small apps, but once there's lots of components angular has to manage it could become death by papercuts! Like you said, a pure pipe is def the way to go IMO.